# Problems with enabling MySQL binary logging in Windows

Tags: mysql, logging

I am trying to enable binary logging on my Windows based MySQL server. I can enable it on my Linux system, but I keep getting errors when trying to invoke mysqld.exe with the --log-bin option.

c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysqld.exe --log-bin[=c:\mysqlbinlog]

100919 15:45:29 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be re
moved in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.

Edit: Turns out I had forgot to restart MySQL server. I thought I had, but some other syntax errors caused it to fault, which I in turn corrected. Thanks for replies, not sure how I should mark this as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error message, it is just a warning. Your binary logs should work just fine.
I would recommend to keep the binary logs somewhere else, probably together with the databases, and definitely not in the root of the C:\ drive.

If you want to get rid of the warning message, have a look at your server config file and change the option for the "default-character-set" into one using "character-set-server".

Comment: 1) That is what I initially thought as well, but when I run "show binary logs" through the MySQL command line client, I get "ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging" 2) It's not an actual live database, it's just for testing purposes, so that's why I'm using such a path.

Comment: Did you any write operations before "show binary logs"?

Answer (score 0):

try using forward slash in the path `c:/mysqlbinlog`